# Generic graphing and charting solutions

Tags: statistics, visualization, generics, charts, graphing

I'm looking for a generic charting solution, ideally not a hosted one that provides the following features:
Charting a tuple of values where the values are:
1) A service identifier (e.g. CPU usage)
2) A client identifier within that service (e.g. server IP)
3) A value
4) A timestamp with millisecond/second resolution.

Optional:
I'd like to also extend the concept of a client identifier further, taking the above example further, I'd like to store statistics for each core separately, so, another identifier would be Core 1/Core 2..

Now, to make sure I'm clearly stating my problem, I don't want a utility that *collects* these statistics. I'd like something that stores them, but, this is also not mandatory, I can always store them in MySQL, or such.

What I'm looking for is something that takes values such as these, and charts them nicely, in a multitude of ways (timelines, motion, and the usual ones [pie, bar..]). Essentially, a nice visualization package that allows me to make use of all this data. I'd be collecting data from multiple services, multiple applications, and the datapoints will be of varying resolution. Some of the data will include multiple layers of nesting, some none. (For example, CPU would go down to Server IP, CPU#, whereas memory would only be Server IP, but would include a different identifier, i.e free/used/cached as the "secondary' identifier. Something like average request latency might not have a secondary identifier at all, in the case of ping). What I'm trying to get across is that having multiple layers of identifiers would be great. To add one final example of where multiple identifiers would be great: adding an extra identifier on top of ip/cpu#, namely, process name. I think the advantages of that are obvious.

For some applications, we might collect data at a very narrow scope, focusing on every aspect, in other cases, it might be a more general statistic. When stuff goes wrong, both come in useful, the first to quickly say "something just went wrong", and the second to say "why?".

Further, it would be a nice thing if the charting application threw out "bad" values, that is, if for some reason our monitoring program started to throw values of 300% CPU used on a single core for 10 seconds, it'd be nice if the charts themselves didn't reflect it in the long run. Some sort of smoothing, maybe? This could obviously be done at the data-layer though, so its not a requirement at all.

Finally, comparing two points in time, or comparing two different client identifiers of the same service etc without too much effort would be great.

I'm not partial to any specific language, although I'd prefer something in (one of the following) PHP, Python, C/C++, C#, as these are languages I'm familiar with. It doesn't have to be open source, it doesn't have to be a library, I'm open to using whatever fits my purpose the best.

More of a P.S than a requirement: I'd like to have pretty charts that are easy for non-technical people to understand, and act upon too (and like looking at!).

I'm open to clarifying, and, in advance, thanks for your time!

Comment: What is the delivery mechanism for the charts? Webpage, local install, Excel...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) meets all your requirements.  But it has a bit of a learning curve.  You are meant to learn by examples, and there are plenty to work from. It makes some pretty nice graphs by default.  Every value can be a function, so you can do things like get rid of your "Bad" values.